# API Key Restriction for Google API Called from URL Fetch within App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-endpoints

I have an API Key for a Google API that I would like to use in all my requests to it. Some of these requests will originate from within a Google App Engine (Python 2.7) application. I had planned to use the UrlFetch library to complete the POST request, basically as follows:

```
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
payload = {'longUrl': request.long_url}
result = urlfetch.fetch([API_REQUEST_URL],
                method=urlfetch.POST,
                payload=json.dumps(payload),
                headers=headers)

json_result = json.loads(result.content)
```

I had set a referrer restriction on my API Key to `*.[my-app].appspot.com/*` with the hope that this would protect my API Key from unauthorized use and negate the need to update an IP-based key restriction (as App Engine IPs change all the time).

This approach as failed me though, because it seems that urlfetch does NOT specify a value for referrer on its own. I assume I could add my own referrer, but then so could anyone else. The approach isn't very secure.

What is the best practice? How should I restrict the key given that I'm using urlfetch from within App Engine? If I do use an HTTP Referrer restriction, which address do I use?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you observed the referrer header can be faked, so setting a referrer restriction on your API Key is rather useless to start with.

But you can add a check based on the `X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid` header, which is sanitized by the GAE infrastructure and precisely identifies the app. From [Issuing a request to another App Engine app](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/issue-requests#issuing_a_request_to_another_app_engine_app):

> When issuing a request to another App Engine app, your App Engine app
>   must assert its identity by adding the header
>   `X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid` to the request. If you instruct the URL
>   Fetch service to not follow redirects, App Engine will add this header
>   to requests automatically.
>
> To instruct the URL Fetch service to not follow redirects, set the
>   `fetch` [`follow_redirects`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.urlfetch#google.appengine.api.urlfetch.fetch) parameter to `False`.
>
> **Note**: If you are making requests to another App Engine application, use its `appspot.com` domain name rather than a custom
>   domain for your app.

Answer (score 2):

You got like this error message?

```
Requests from referer <empty> are blocked.
```

`urlfetch` seems not to attach `Refer` automatically, so you should set `Refer` in your request header.

```
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json','Referer': '*.[my-app].appspot.com/*'}
```